# Split list which is consisted of spacing words which is between words

Tags: list, split, cpu-word, spacing

I read csv file as:

```
pd.read_csv('abc.csv').head
```

and I am sorting of different items by list.

So I dragged some columns, copy and paste to list.

But when I paste it, it shows like as below:

[image]

I want to split that list as below:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

What would be the most simple way?

I also want to know how to split:

```
[a b c d e]
```

Comment: More code would be very useful. What does the `abc.csv` look like? Show the code for the operations you are performing after reading. What do you mean by copy and paste?

Comment: Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories. Is this `pandas`?